# Why is :target pseudo class not working in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, target

I am making use of :target pseudo class but however it is not working in IE browser (7 and 8).

I used selectivizr javascript but its still not working.

So is there any other way to make it work?
Is it possible by means of jQuery?

Comment: can you show your code or Fiddle it?

Answer (score 5):

The `:target` pseudo class is supported only in IE9. Refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/:target)

Answer (score 1):

When using jQuery, instead of `:target`, you can just use `$(location.hash)` and, if it exists, that will be your `:target` element.

Answer (score 0):

I think even *Modernizr* will not help you. The `:target` pseudo class is hard to detect by a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) — worked for me in `IE8`! Not in `IE7` though. Give edge release a try:

```
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/keithclark/selectivizr/master/selectivizr.js"></script>
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="[fallback css]" /></noscript>
<![endif]-->
```